# Issue in parsing csv data php | regex replace commas inside of quotes

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

Anyone share code in php to parse csv data . While am parsing data i got values inside double quotes as separate array so my logic will change . I need to store this data to mysql DB. My sample csv file is below

```
com,24,2.1.0.5,en,mido,2020-11-01T03:29:32Z,1604201372915,2020-11-01T03:29:32Z,1604201372915,5,,Nice,2020-11-01T06:34:23Z,1604212463397,"Hi Raju, Thank you so much",497230

com,24,2.1.0.5,en,athene_f,2020-11-01T04:19:52Z,1604204392095,2020-11-01T04:19:52Z,1604204392095,5,,So so,2020-11-01T06:33:58Z,1604212438170,"Hi dev, Thanks",497230
```

code

```
$csv_file = 'csv/test.csv';

$file = fopen($csv_file, "r");
fgetcsv($file);
$count=0;
while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
$getData = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $getData);
$getData = implode(",", $getData);
$getData = '\''.substr($getData , 1, -1).'\'';
$getData =explode(",", $getData);
$exp_array = explode(",", $getData);
$package_name  = trim($getData[0]); 
$app_version_code  = trim($getData[1]); 
$app_version_name  = trim($getData[2]); 
$reviewer_language = trim($getData[3]); 

 ob_get_clean();

}
```

**expected output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => com
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 2.1.0.5
    [3] => en
    [4] => mido
    [5] => 2020-11-01T03:29:32Z
    [6] => 1604201372915
    [7] => 2020-11-01T03:29:32Z
    [8] => 1604201372915
    [9] => 5
    [10] => 
    [11] => Nice
    [12] => 2020-11-01T06:34:23Z
    [13] => 1604212463397
    [14] => Hi Raju, Thank you so much
    [15] => 497230
)
```

Comment: Are you basically asking how to deal with commas nested inside of quotes?

Comment: yes i need to parse that data as single value inside nested quotes

Comment: Ok. Well i'd suggest renaming the title of your question to "regex replace commas inside of quotes" or something similar. You will need to replace the commas inside of quotes *before* you do the csv parser command.

Comment: comma seperated logic is not working , i created a seperate parse to find and replace comma inside quote but that is also not working

Comment: changed title by adding regex replace commas inside of quotes

Comment: `fgetcsv` should parse for you. If you have to `explode` something's not right. `$getData` should be an array.

Comment: @tadman OP has some commas inside a field that are getting parsed due to nature of the command.

Comment: Could you update your question and include the result you are getting and what you expect to get?

Comment: @GetSet If the CSV parsing is set up right, it should properly handle quotes.

Comment: Per @tadman, Code Mania you can specify an "enclosure". I haven't tested whether this option will ignore on those fields that dont have the "enclosure" but you sure can. Heres the doc ref https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: updated expected output what i want

Comment: @tadman function arrayFromCSV($file, $hasFieldNames = false, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure='') {   }   what i need to give in $enclosure

Comment: Use the PHP builtins for this. Don't cobble together your own. `fgetcsv()` has an enclosure option which should be `'"'` by default.

Comment: @cully updated desired output

Comment: @tadman can you please help with code

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this and got the output you indicated you were expecting:

```php
<?php

$file = fopen('input.txt', "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

Here's `input.txt`:

```
com,24,2.1.0.5,en,mido,2020-11-01T03:29:32Z,1604201372915,2020-11-01T03:29:32Z,1604201372915,5,,Nice,2020-11-01T06:34:23Z,1604212463397,"Hi Raju, Thank you so much",497230
com,24,2.1.0.5,en,athene_f,2020-11-01T04:19:52Z,1604204392095,2020-11-01T04:19:52Z,1604204392095,5,,So so,2020-11-01T06:33:58Z,1604212438170,"Hi dev, Thanks",497230
```

And here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => com
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 2.1.0.5
    [3] => en
    [4] => mido
    [5] => 2020-11-01T03:29:32Z
    [6] => 1604201372915
    [7] => 2020-11-01T03:29:32Z
    [8] => 1604201372915
    [9] => 5
    [10] =>
    [11] => Nice
    [12] => 2020-11-01T06:34:23Z
    [13] => 1604212463397
    [14] => Hi Raju, Thank you so much
    [15] => 497230
)
Array
(
    [0] => com
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 2.1.0.5
    [3] => en
    [4] => athene_f
    [5] => 2020-11-01T04:19:52Z
    [6] => 1604204392095
    [7] => 2020-11-01T04:19:52Z
    [8] => 1604204392095
    [9] => 5
    [10] =>
    [11] => So so
    [12] => 2020-11-01T06:33:58Z
    [13] => 1604212438170
    [14] => Hi dev, Thanks
    [15] => 497230
)
```

If you are not getting the expected output, one other thing to check is the file encoding on your CSV file. It could be that your PHP script is expecting your file to be utf-8 encoded, but your file is using another encoding. There are lots of resources online for detecting file encoding and converting using PHP.

Comment: Thanks , it working fine from reading contents from txt file . I have csv file csv file has still issue. Is there any way to read csv and write that content as text file

Comment: can you please try same content with csv comma delimited . It is not getting . I have data's in csv format

Comment: Interesting. But how would `fgetscsv()` know the file extension when a handle is being passed? Possibly a difference in PHP versions to do the expected deed.

Comment: @CodeMania, a .csv file is a plain text file. The extension shouldn't matter but apparently it does. Which PHP ver are you using?

Comment: @cully   output while ready from csv file ```  Array
(
    [0] => "com
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 2.1.0.5
    [3] => en
    [4] => mido
    [5] => 2020-11-01T03:29:32Z
    [6] => 1604201372915
    [7] => 2020-11-01T03:29:32Z
    [8] => 1604201372915
    [9] => 5
    [10] => 
    [11] => Nice=�M�=�M�
    [12] => 2020-11-01T06:34:23Z
    [13] => 1604212463397
    [14] => ""Hi Raju
    [15] =>  Thank you so much""
    [16] => 497230"

)  ```

Comment: @CodeMania The file extension doesn't make any difference. You might want to check the file encoding on your CSV file. It may be that your PHP script is trying to read the file as utf-8, but your file is not utf-8 encoded.

Comment: @cully my issue is still not resolved . i loaded by csv but comma separation splits data to different arrays [14] => ""Hi Raju [15] => Thank you so much"" [16] . I opened csv and copied content and paste that to one txt file . that is working

Comment: @CodeMania Like I said, did you check the file encoding on the CSV file? Also, try renaming your TXT file that works to CSV and see if it still works (don't use your original file, just copy the TXT file that works).

Comment: Possibly @Cully OP is using an earlier PHP ver. OP is not really reading comments thoroughly looks like. Asked on PHP ver, no reply. Quick fixes might be the order of tonite. ...... A double quote char is standard ascii and not specific to utf8

Comment: Agree tho that could be a utf8 issue or other encoding @Cully. Because if OP opened the file the cut and pasted to a new file and then saved as `.txt` (or any extension imaginable) then the source file encoding would have been lost on the save and saved to whatever default encoding of the editor, that did work. .... Shouldn't matter tho unless this is anomaly of an older PHP ver.

Comment: @GetSet used preg_replace and added code in the post. Can u verify

Comment: @CodeMania Did you try what I suggested in my prevous comment?

Answer (score 0):

These 2 lines are 100% incorrect...

```
$getData =explode(",", $getData);
$exp_array = explode(",", $getData);
```

givn, that $getData contains a string, after explode() it will be an array (reassigned to $getData).

On the next line, this array is tried to be exploded again, but this will fail and give you warnings or errors.

Turn up error reporting level and display all errors on screen during development.